# vbs split file and send each row by mail

Tags: vbscript

my script below put the entire content of a file in a body of email to be send,now i want to send  only each row of my file(my file have 8 columns delimit with pipe "|") by email using this  template for body of email:

```
Code:<value in file> Operator:<value in file>
Number:<value in file> Amount:<value in file>
NID:<value in file> Name:<value in file>
DATE:<value in file> HOUR:<value in file>
*****
see the script
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "C:\link of my file\output.txt\output.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\link of my file\output.txt")
If objFile.Size > 0 Then

Dim objCDO1
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
'objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file  ."&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"
'objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file  "&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&""&f.ReadAll&""&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"
objCDO1.AddAttachment("C:\link of my file\output.txt")
f.Close
objCDO1.TO ="adr1@test.com"
objCDO1.From = "adr2@test.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
objCDO1.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mysmtp"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objCDO1.Send
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
ELSE
Wscript.Echo "no file"
End If
```

Comment: Did not understand your question. What exactly do you want to send? Whole file in mail or each line in separate mails or delimited column split apart in separate email?

Comment: Exactly I want to sent each line in separate mails  @MithileshIndurkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly.

```
Code:<value in file> Operator:<value in file>
Number:<value in file> Amount:<value in file>
NID:<value in file> Name:<value in file>
DATE:<value in file> HOUR:<value in file>
*****
see the script
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "C:\link of my file\output.txt\output.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\link of my file\output.txt")
If objFile.Size > 0 Then

Dim objCDO1
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
'objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file  ."&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"
'objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
 strFileText = f.ReadAll
 f.Close
 arrFileText = Split(strFileText, vbcrLF) 'split the file content by line feed character
For intArrCounter = 0 to uBound(arrFileText)


ArrLineContent = Split(arrFileText(intArrCounter)),"|")

Code = ArrLineContent(0)
Operator = ArrLineContent(1)
```

' create variables for all the remaining columns. Use them the way you like in the textbody.

```
objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file"&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&""&arrFileText(intArrCounter)&""&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"
objCDO1.AddAttachment("C:\link of my file\output.txt")

objCDO1.TO ="adr1@test.com"
objCDO1.From = "adr2@test.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
objCDO1.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
    objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
  objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mysmtp"

objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
        objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
        objCDO1.Send
    Next
    Set f = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    ELSE
    Wscript.Echo "no file"
    End If
```

You may need a little bit of debugging on this one.

Comment: It works but how to have the information on the body of the mail respecting my template above

Comment: Updated my original answer. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.

Comment: each  variables i have to create will receive value corresponding columns,how to use it in textbody?

Comment: objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file"&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"Code = "& 
 Code &vbcrLF & "Operator = " & Operator & vbcrLF(Enter all your variables here just like code and operator variables are mentioned)&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"